# Issue with SUMPRODUCT Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am Having a issue with the SUMPRODUCT Function in Excel 2007.  Here is my string and issue:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$800>DATE(2013,4,1))*($B$2:$B$800< DATE(2013,4,5)))
```

```
A      B
1   4/1/2013
2   4/2/2013
3   4/2/2013
4   4/2/2013
5   4/2/2013
6   4/2/2013
7   4/4/2013
8   4/4/2013
9   4/4/2013
10  4/5/2013
11  4/5/2013
12  4/8/2013
13  4/8/2013
14  4/8/2013
15  4/8/2013
16  4/8/2013
17  4/9/2013
18  4/9/2013
19  4/9/2013
20  4/9/2013
21  4/9/2013
```

The Value returned is 8 even though the answer is 11.  I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  Can somebody please help me.

Comment: Try the count function to see how many dates are actually counted.

Answer (score 2):

8 looks right to me - by using > and < you are excluding the boundary dates, if you want to include those use >= and <=, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$800>=DATE(2013,4,1))*($B$2:$B$800<=DATE(2013,4,5)))`

Comment: Thanks That was it! I kew I was close just needed a little push and help